# Magento - How to add static block on side columns in home page

Tags: php, html, magento

I use default home page which layout is "2 columns with right bar", it looks to me what ever I added in content just showing in middle column. Question is how to add my static blocks/products on left/right column, say replace the compare products or append after it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From the Admin panel, select CMS > Pages > Manage Content.

Click to open the CMS for your homepage. Then, in the Page
    Information panel on the left, select Design.

In the Layout Update XML box, enter the code for the right sidebar,
    as shown below. Change the block_id to the identifer of the block to
    be placed.

```
<reference name="right">
<block type="cms/block" name="right.permanent.callout">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>***your-block***</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Comment: This is the best solution IMO for a per page block addition. Maybe there is a (better/easier/other -- pick what you like the best) way if the OP want it on all the CMS page, but this is not clearly stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use widgets.

You can create a block and add that as a widget into anywhere. You can even add that block into your .phtml files...

here is very good tutorial 
http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_widgets.htm